# Loadrunner cannot sniff traffic of the android emulator while connected on VPN that disconnects network

Tags: android-emulator, performance-testing, vpn, loadrunner

I'm want to see the traffic sent and received from an **app** installed on android **emulator** while being connected to a **private VPN**

currently i'm using the **loadrunner** recorder to sniff this traffic of the app on the **emulator** but i does not show any requests or responses.

on the other hand when i try to record any of the available websites while connected on the **vpn** on the google chrome the **loadrunner** capture these traffic normally.

Is there any ***configurations*** that should be adjusted on the **emulator**? as in my opinion *that the IP of the **emulator** is not the same as the one of the* **VPN**.

Is there any ***configurations*** that should be adjusted on the **emulator**?

Answer (score 0):

You need your proxy recorder to be in the same network as your emulator which is generating HTML.  Then you can have a "man in the middle" proxy recording of the behavior.

If you emulator is on VPN and the host of your recorder is not, then you are likely out of luck.  However, connect your parent OS to the VPN, which is also running VUGEN and the Emulator, then set your emulator to the recording proxy of VUGEN and you are likely golden.